# How to Store Http json data into variables and calculate with firestore data Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, http

How to take http json data and store in variables and in the same page read firestore data and calculate with reference to http json data and display

Example: Json Data : a=1,b=2,c=3
Firestore Data : d=4,e=5,f=6

How to do sum= a*d ? in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the async requests to complete before you do the calculation.

You can use `Future.wait()` to wait for the two async requests to  be called and ended.

Example:

```
Future.wait([ getDataFromAPI(),getDataFromFirebase()]);
```

You can set the result from api and firebase to their respective variables and once the future is completed, you can perform the operation you wanted.

Comment: without putting them into stream or future builder, in body how to access the data in variables, to show them we use builder but firestore and http use two seperate builders, thay can be streamed in same builder ?